# C++ Partial-specialization of class in source not header

Tags: c++, partial-specialization, template-classes

Foo.h

```
template<typename A, typename B>
class Foo{
public:
  Foo();
  /*..*/
};
```

Foo.cpp

```
template<typename A, typename B>
Foo<A, B>::Foo(){/*...*/}

template<typename A>
Foo<A, Beta>::Foo(){/* some specialized construction */} //<- this doesn't work.

template<>
Foo<Alpha, Beta>::Foo(){/*...*/} // <-will work, but I want partial specialization.
```

When I compile, the partially specialized constructor throws an error

> nested name specifier 'Foo::' for declaration does not refer into a class, class template or class template partial specialization

I imagine I need to declare this partially-specialized class somewhere, but I don't want to have to keep re-declaring the same class ... ie I don't want to have to put the following in the header file:

```
template<typename A>
class Foo_Beta : public Foo<A, Beta>{
public:
  Foo_Beta();
}

//in cpp
template<typename A>
Foo_Beta<A>() : Foo<A, Beta>() {/**specialized constructor stuff**/}
```

Because then I can't construct *Foo()* that uses the Foo_Beta constructor.

I've tried

```
template<typename A>
class Foo<A,Beta> : public Foo<A, Beta>{
public:
  Foo();
}
```

but that doesn't compile either.

**Essentially, what is the syntax to declare the partial specialization of a class without re-declaring all the internal functions to that class?**

Comment: A partial specialization is still a template; why would you put it in a .cpp file? Anyway, the question seems to be more about how to partially specialize a member function of a class template without replacing the entire class. Unfortunately, this is not possible. You can't partially specialize function templates, and that includes member functions of class templates.

Comment: The example you show with `Foo_Beta` is not partial specialization. Partial specialization would be e.g. `template<typename A> class Foo<A, Beta> { ... };`

Comment: @SebastianRedl: I suspected that may be the case. Mostly what I wanted was a clean "if you get Beta construct this way, Beth the other way, and it doesn't matter whether A is Alpha or Aleph." Aside from the constructor though, the class behaves the same for any combination A, B it will receive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You said:

> `template<typename A>
>     Foo<A, Beta>::Foo(){/* some specialized construction */} //<- this doesn't work.`

You can use that only if you specialize the entire class. You can't specialize just one member function of the class.

The following should work:

```
template<typename A> class Foo<A, Beta>
{
   Foo();
};

template<typename A> 
Foo<A, Beta>::Foo()
{
}
```

Comment: "I imagine I need to declare this partially-specialized class somewhere, but I don't want to have to keep re-declaring the same class..."

Comment: @0x499602D2 If the reality is that I must keep re-declaring the class, that's the reality. It sucks I guess... but that may just be the limitation of the syntax

Comment: @r-sahu, must I add the
`template<typename A> class Foo<A, Beta>
{
  Foo();
};`

to the header, or can it be in the source file?

Also, I mean... there are a lot of other functions that are common to them, do I need to include those functions in the specialization?

Comment: @shavera, the answer is "yes" to both questions. Once you create a specialization of the class template, it is unrelated to the original class template.

Comment: @r-sahu, ugh. this becomes frustrating. I think it's probably back to the drawing board on the whole design. I had some assumptions about template classes that I guess simply don't bear out. Which is too bad, because ultimately it seems like the right approach...

Comment: @shavera, "back to the drawing board" is only a temporary set back. Once you have cleaned up the design, I have a feeling you will be glad you took the time to design the program well.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by others - you cannot partially specialise a function. However, you can defer work in template functions to specialised implementation functions, which does give the effect of partial specialisation, for instance:

```
template<class X>
X make_a_B()
{
    return X();  // default implementation
}

template<>
Beta make_a_B<Beta>()
{
    Beta b;
    // do custom things with b...
    return b;  // fully specialised for Beta, everything else uses default case.
}

template<class X>
X make_an_A()
{
    return X();
}

template<typename A, typename B>
class Foo{
public:
    Foo()
    : _myA( make_an_A<A>() )
    , _myB( make_a_B<B>() )
    {}

    /*..*/
    A _myA;
    B _myB;
};
```

`Foo<Alpha, Beta>()` will now behave differently to `Foo<Alpha, Gamma>()`

Comment: This seems like a useful solution.

I think, however, I'm going to go with (what feels to me very poor design)

    Foo<A, B>(){
      if(typeID(Beta) == typeID(B)) doBetaConstructionStuff();
      if(typeID(Beth) == typeID(B)) doBethConstructionStuff();
    }

Comment: No, you're right, that was a bad design. I'm going with the template specialization below after all.

Comment: That's great news shavera. A little work now will save many painful days in the future.